# Django - File Upload: Open the file as text instead of bytes

Tags: python, django, csv, encoding, utf-8

On Python 3.3 and Django 1.6

Is it possible, in a ModelForm's View, to open an uploaded file as a text file instead of bytes ?

Here's some example code :

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Methode POST
    Utilisé lors de l'envoie du formulaire
    :return: Soit un message de succès, soit le formulaire retourné avec erreurs
    """
    form = FormulaireUploadFichierDonnee(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        fichier = request.FILES['fichier']
        volet = form.cleaned_data['volet']

        validateur = ValidateurFactory.factory(volet)

        compteur_erreurs = 0
        liste_obj = []
        liste_erreurs = []

        for ligne in fichier.readlines():
            validateur.ligne = ligne.split('\t')
            obj =  validateur.creer_objet()
            if obj:
                liste_obj.append(obj)
            else:
                compteur_erreurs += 1
                liste_erreurs.append(ligne)

        if liste_obj:
            instance = UploadFichierDonnees(fichier=request.FILES['fichier'])
            instance.utilisateur = request.user
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponse(str(liste_obj) + "<br> Erreurs: " + str(compteur_erreurs))
        else:
            return HttpResponse(str(liste_erreurs) + "<br> Erreurs: " + str(compteur_erreurs))

    else:
        return render(request, 'tabstat/vue_ajout_fichier.html', {
            'form': form,
        })
```

Basically I need to loop over every line in the file, split them on tabs and process data from there with a validator. The problem is I can't get the string object, I get a byte string.

I tried decoding it with `.decode('utf-8')`:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 62: invalid continuation byte`

and `.decode('ascii')`:

`'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 62: ordinal not in range(128)`

, without success.  I tried with the CSV reader (as it's a CSV file), but it refuses to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems it was only an encoding problem.

Tried other decoding modes, and found out that `latin-1` was the right one.